# Force mongo to store values in lowercase

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Currently I'm calling .toLower() before inserting into a collection:

```
site.Name = site.Name.ToLower();
collection.Insert(site);
```

I see an article([How to force mongo to store members in lowercase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981897/how-to-force-mongo-to-store-members-in-lowercase)) that forces member names to be lowercase, but can't find info on forcing the values to be lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Doing so, be it manually or in an automated manner, seems rather dangerous, because it's a lossy operation. There are cases when transforming data on insert is appropriate, e.g. when normalizing strings to be better searchable, but generally speaking, I'd say it's a bad idea. Transform data on read from the client or on read from the database.

An alternative is to add a computed field:

```
public string NormalizedName {
  get { return Name.ToLowerInvariant(); }
  set { } // also hacky,
}
```

Especially in string searches this can also be used to remove or replace problematic UTF-8 characters.

Comment: My queries are case insensitive: sites.Where(x => x.Name.ToLower() == filter.Name.ToLower());  But, I'm trying prevent multiple copies of "www.site.com", "WWW.SITE.COM", "wWw.SiTe.CoM", etc being inserted.

Comment: In that case, I'd definitely recommend performing the `ToLower()` when reading the data from the client in the controller, or using the computed field to search on. LINQ `Where()` and mongodb's `$where` are slow (both can't use an index). Instead, put an index on `NormalizedName` and `Find<Foo>(Builders<Foo>.EQ(p => p.NormalizedName, filter.Name.ToLowerInvariant()))`. Another option is to make the class' constructor perform the conversion, i.e. `Foo(name) { this.Name = name.ToLowerInvariant() }`

Comment: I went with a custom serializer that lowercases strings.  I wanted to share it here but I can't seem to get code to format right in the comment box